# how to specify version when installing packages using dpkg

Tags: python, dpkg

I would like to install psycopg for python on a server but I am having some version problem. Is there a way I can specify which version to use during installation?

Here is what I have

```
dpkg -l |grep python
ii  python                             2.7.3-4+deb7u1                all          interactive high-level object-oriented language (default version)
ii  python-central                     0.6.17                        all          register and build utility for Python packages
iU  python-psycopg2                    2.4.5-1                       amd64        Python module for PostgreSQL
ii  python2.6                          2.6.8-1.1                     amd64        Interactive high-level object-oriented language (version 2.6)
ii  python2.7                          2.7.3-6                       amd64        Interactive high-level object-oriented language (version 2.7)
```

I would like to use python2.6.8-1.1 to install psycopg but this is what I get when I try to install

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python-psycopg2:
 python-psycopg2 depends on python-egenix-mxdatetime; however:
  Package python-egenix-mxdatetime is not installed.
 python-psycopg2 depends on python (<< 2.7); however:
  Version of python on system is 2.7.3-4+deb7u1.

dpkg: error processing python-psycopg2 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python-psycopg2
```

How can I setup and specify to use python version 2.6.8-1.1?

Comment: You may want to consider virtual environments, cf. installing and using virtualenv and virtualenv-wrapper on your (Debian-based) system.

Comment: This question is not about programming.  Please consider asking it in other sites like http://superuser.com/ or http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks for the tip pyStarter. Thanks Juan for the heads up

Answer (score 0):

When installing system packages, you get the system packaged version.  If those versions happen to be incompatible between packages, that is a problem you should submit to the maintainers.

If you want another python interpreter version, there may be a repository for it, otherwise you'll just have to download the source and compile it yourself.

If you want to control the versions of the Python packages (not the interpreter), you should set up a [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/virtualenv.html) and install into it with [pip](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/).  Now activate the virtualenv when you want to run a script with those dependencies.

```
virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python2.6 my_env
source my_env/bin/activate
pip install psycopg2
```